# Merge Sort - getting incorrect results and corrupted data (duplicating the elements)

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, mergesort

I try to implement the basic Merge Sort, however something goes wrong and it incorrectly duplicates some elements in my input array and even changes some elements, so the output array becomes corrupted. I use `tmp[]` as a global declared array pointer (`long *tmp;` -> in global declarations) What am I missing or making wrong?

Also, how can I improve the time complexity of this algorithm?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void merge(long *arr, int l, int m, int r);
void mergeSort(long *arr, int l, int r);

//Global Declarations
long *tmp;

//Merge Sort
void Merge_Sort(long *Array, int Size) {
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(long) * Size);
    mergeSort(Array, 0, Size - 1);
}

//Merge Sort helper function
void mergeSort(long *arr, int l, int r) {
    if (l >= r)
        return;
    // divide the array into two arrays
    // call mergeSort with each array
    // merge the two arrays into one

    int m = l + ((r - l) / 2; //integer overflow

    mergeSort(arr, l, m);
    mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r);
    merge(arr, l, m, r);
} 

//merge function
static void merge(long *arr, int l, int m, int r) {   
    //tmp[] is a global array with the same size as arr[]
    memcpy(&tmp[l], &arr[l], m - l + 1); //copy left subarray to tmp
    memcpy(&tmp[m + 1], &arr[m + 1], r - m); //copy right subarray to tmp

    int i = l;
    int j = m + 1;
    for (int k = l; k <= r; k++) {
        if (i > m)
            arr[k] = tmp[j++]; //if the left sub-array is exhausted
        else
        if (j > r)
            arr[k] = tmp[i++]; //if the right sub-array is exhausted
        else
        if (tmp[j] < tmp[i])
            arr[k] = tmp[j++]; //compare the current values
        else
            arr[k] = tmp[i++];
    }
}

int main() {
    long array[10] = {
        -3153274050600690459,
        6569843820458972605,
        -6837880721686463424,
        1876340121514080353,
        -1767506107468465601,
        -1913444019437311076,
        -426543213433372251,
        6724963487502039099,
        -1272217999899710623,
        3399373277871640777,
    };
    Merge_Sort(array, 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         printf("%ld\n". array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output (incorrect):

```
-1913444019437311076
-426543213433372251
140464981228095
140388532523709
94285492859968
94285492861503
-1767506107468465601
6724963487502039099
-1272217999899710623
3399373277871640777
```

Expected output:

```
-6837880721686463424
-3153274050600690459
-1913444019437311076
-1767506107468465601
-1272217999899710623
-426543213433372251
1876340121514080353
3399373277871640777
6569843820458972605
6724963487502039099
```

Comment: Consider using built-in sort functions of c like here: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61042309/how-to-merge-sort-struct-with-strings/61042631#61042631)

Comment: Is your array huge enough to get an integer overflow here: `int m = l +((r - l) / 2; //integer overflow`?. There should be >1B elements to get an overflow here.

Comment: I train the algorithm with large arrays as well @user3365922

Comment: You should not forget to de-allocate the merge buffer (`tmp`) after you are done with it.  Moreover, it would be better to make it a local variable of `Merge_Sort()`, and to pass it as an argument to other functions that need it.  Make a habit of avoiding global variables as much as possible, at least mutable ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `merge` function does not copy the correct number of bytes:

```
memcpy(&tmp[l], &arr[l], m - l + 1); //copy left subarray to tmp
memcpy(&tmp[m + 1], &arr[m + 1], r - m); //copy right subarray to tmp
```

You must compute the correct number of bytes by multiplying the number of elements by the size of the element. Note also that the left and right subarrays are contiguous, so it suffices to write:

```
memcpy(&tmp[l], &arr[l], sizeof(*tmp) * (r - l + 1));
```

There are other problems:

- avoid using a global variable `tmp`, just pass it to `mergeSort` as an extra argument
- you must free the temporary array after `mergeSort()` finishes.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//merge function
static void merge(long *arr, int l, int m, int r, long *tmp) {   
    //tmp[] is a global array with the same size as arr[]
    memcpy(&tmp[l], &arr[l], sizeof(*tmp) * (r - l + 1));

    for (int k = l, i = l, j = m + 1; k <= r; k++) {
        if (i <= m && (j > r || tmp[i] <= tmp[j]))
            arr[k] = tmp[i++];
        else
            arr[k] = tmp[j++];
    }
}

//Merge Sort helper function
static void mergeSort(long *arr, int l, int r, long *tmp) {
    if (l < r) {
        // divide the array into two arrays
        // call mergeSort with each array
        // merge the two arrays into one
        int m = l + (r - l) / 2; //avoid integer overflow

        mergeSort(arr, l, m, tmp);
        mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r, tmp);
        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
} 

//Merge Sort
void Merge_Sort(long *array, int size) {
    long *tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp) * size);
    mergeSort(array, 0, Size - 1, tmp);
    free(tmp);
}
```

Regarding your other question: *how can I improve the time complexity of this algorithm?*

The merge sort algorithm has a time complexity of **O(N * log(N))** regardless of the set distribution. This is considered optimal for generic data. If your data happens to have known specific characteristics, other algorithms may have a lower complexity.

- if all values are n a small range, [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) is a good alternative
- if there are many duplicates and a small number K of distinct unique values, the complexity can be reduced to **O(N + K.log(K))**.
- integer values can be sorted with [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) that can be more efficient for large arrays.
- if the array is almost sorted, [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) or a modified merge sort (testing if the left and right subarrays are already in order with a single initial test) can be faster too.
- Using [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) can result in faster execution for many non random distributions.

Here is an implementation of `radix_sort()` for arrays of `long`:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void radix_sort(long *a, size_t size) {
    size_t counts[sizeof(*a)][256] = {{ 0 }}, *cp;
    size_t i, sum;
    unsigned int n;
    unsigned long *tmp, *src, *dst, *aa;

    dst = tmp = malloc(size * sizeof(*a));
    src = (unsigned long *)a;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        unsigned long v = src[i] + (unsigned long)VAL_MIN;
        for (n = 0; n < sizeof(*a) * 8; n += 8)
            counts[n >> 3][(v >> n) & 255]++;
    }
    for (n = 0; n < sizeof(*a) * 8; n += 8) {
        cp = &counts[n >> 3][0];
        for (i = 0, sum = 0; i < 256; i++)
            cp[i] = (sum += cp[i]) - cp[i];
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            dst[cp[((src[i] + (unsigned long)VAL_MIN) >> n) & 255]++] = src[i];
        aa = src;
        src = dst;
        dst = aa;
    }
    if (src == tmp)
        memcpy(a, src, size * sizeof(*a));
    free(tmp);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help! How can I improve this algorithm timewise?

Comment: @MertZamir:  try using Timsort or my `radix_sort` above.